# Use GQL to delete database that are one week old in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gql

Wondering if GQL could let me delete datas that are one week or older using gql, been finding work around with this, and it just seems to be  a lot of hassel.

I have a database in google app engine, table name Tracker, consist of id, and int, the indexes for the table, current,an int, the DateTime of the incident and location, a string.

What I need to do now is, to delete off datas that are one week and older, compare to my latest date in database. somehow like dateadd function of sql if possible.

But it seems like GQL has limitations to do that, does anyone have any solutions? :)

**Your help is greatly appreciated :)**

Comment: GQL only supports SELECT, so no, it cannot be used to delete anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, so that means if i want to delete datas in google app engine, i would need to do it manually in google app engine itself?

Comment: It can be done programatically, but not using GQL statements. You basically need to fetch the entities (or their keys anyway) and then delete them. (Sorry, I don't know the specifics of how this is done in JPA).